# Replace a text with increasing number using regex in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Sample String :**

```
<TemperatureRange min="min3" max="max3" uom="uom13" code="1013" />
<TemperatureRange min="min4" max="max4" uom="uom13" code="1013" />
```

**Find What :** `<TemperatureRange min="min.*" max="max.*" u`

**Replace With :** `<TemperatureRange min="10" max="10" u`

**Output :**

```
<TemperatureRange min="10" max="10" uom="uom13" code="1013" />
<TemperatureRange min="10" max="10" uom="uom13" code="1013" />
```

**Expected Output :**

```
<TemperatureRange min="10" max="10" uom="uom13" code="1013" />
<TemperatureRange min="11" max="11" uom="uom13" code="1013" />
```

Comment: You can't do this with straight regex, but you can try using a scripting language

Comment: I'm fairly sure that regex is too static to be able to accomplish this. Would a python script be acceptable instead?

Comment: Regexes match patterns in text. They do *not* do math for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Notepad++, I'm going to assume you have powershell.

Feel free to improve on the code here as it probably isn't too efficient, but it should get you what you need.  I made it so that you can even start with different numbers for min and max.

```
function ReplaceFirstOccurrence ([string] $Source, [string]$Find, [string]$Replace)
{
    $Place = $Source.IndexOf($Find);

    $result = $Source.Remove($Place, $Find.Length).Insert($Place, $Replace);
    return $result;
}


$text = @"
<TemperatureRange min="min3" max="max3" uom="uom13" code="10131" />
<TemperatureRange min="min3" max="max3" uom="uom13" code="10132" />
<TemperatureRange min="min3" max="max3" uom="uom13" code="10133" />
<TemperatureRange min="min3" max="max3" uom="uom13" code="10134" />
"@
#alternatively, you can read text from file with Get-Content -Path c:\path\to\file.txt

$findWhat = @"
<TemperatureRange min="min.*" max="max.*" u
"@

$replaceWithTemplate = @"
<TemperatureRange min="{num1}" max="{num2}" u
"@

$startNums = @{}
$startNums["{num1}"] = 10
$startNums["{num2}"] = 10


$matches = [regex]::Matches($text, $findWhat)
$outputResult=$text

foreach ( $match in $matches){

    $replaceWith = $replaceWithTemplate 
    foreach($key in $($startNums.Keys))
    {
        $replaceWith = $replaceWith -replace $key,$startNums[$key]        
        $startNums[$key]++
    }

    $outputResult = ReplaceFirstOccurrence $outputResult $match.Value $replaceWith
}

$outputResult
```

The result is:

```
 <TemperatureRange min="10" max="10" uom="uom13" code="10131" />
 <TemperatureRange min="11" max="11" uom="uom13" code="10132" />
 <TemperatureRange min="12" max="12" uom="uom13" code="10133" />
 <TemperatureRange min="13" max="13" uom="uom13" code="10134" />
```

Comment: This took me way longer to write than I expected... because Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If the lines you expect to replace are all together, you may do the following:

Replace by (no numbers):

`<TemperatureRange min="" max="" uom="uom13" code="1013" />`

Use notepad++'s Column editor (Edit => Column editor/ALT+C). That will let you fill the columns with consecutive numbers.

See: 
[Notepad++ sorting/replacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336350/notepad-sorting-replacing)