# Notepad++ sorting/replacing

Tags: notepad++

I have a list like this

```
class TRYK_U_B_Sage_Tshirt
class TRYK_U_B_BLK3CD
class TRYK_U_B_BLK3CD_Tshirt
class TRYK_U_B_BLK
class TRYK_U_B_BLK_Tshirt
class TRYK_U_B_BLKTAN
class TRYK_U_B_BLKTAN_Tshirt
class TRYK_U_B_ODTAN
class TRYK_U_B_ODTAN_Tshirt
class TRYK_U_B_BLK_OD
class TRYK_U_B_BLK_OD_Tshirt
class TRYK_U_B_C01_Tsirt
class TRYK_U_B_C02_Tsirt
class TRYK_U_B_OD_BLK
class TRYK_U_B_OD_BLK_2
class TRYK_U_B_BLK_TAN_1
```

I want to add the following to the end of each line = `{ quality = 1; price = n+1; };` 
This is the output I am looking for

```
class TRYK_U_B_Sage_Tshirt              { quality = 1; price = 1; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLK3CD                   { quality = 1; price = 2; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLK3CD_Tshirt            { quality = 1; price = 3; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLK                      { quality = 1; price = 4; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLK_Tshirt               { quality = 1; price = 5; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLKTAN                   { quality = 1; price = 6; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLKTAN_Tshirt            { quality = 1; price = 7; };
class TRYK_U_B_ODTAN                    { quality = 1; price = 8; };
class TRYK_U_B_ODTAN_Tshirt             { quality = 1; price = 9; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLK_OD                   { quality = 1; price = 10; };
class TRYK_U_B_BLK_OD_Tshirt            { quality = 1; price = 11; };
class TRYK_U_B_C01_Tsirt                { quality = 1; price = 12; };
class TRYK_U_B_C02_Tsirt                { quality = 1; price = 13; };
```

Something like \n{ quality = 1; price = **what do I do here..;** };

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching and found out that I can use "Coloumn Editor" to do this. Original post is not "true" since I already had the "{ quality =..." data in my first list. And everything is alinged so it took me a few seconds to do this.

Hold down ALT and select the numbers you want to replace. Go to Edit -> Columun Editor and it is pretty self explanatory